# javascript fabricjs filter do not return filtered canvas to url

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

```
export function filter(url) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas')
    c.id = "canvas_greyscale"
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_greyscale')
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
        c.height = oImg.height
        c.width = oImg.width
        oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
        oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
        canvas.add(oImg)
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        console.log(img)
        return img
    }, {crossOrigin: "Anonymous"})
}
```

Here my canvas is rendered with grayscale filter. It does not have issue but when I try to convert canvas to url it is giving me the canvas without filter.

I dont know whats wrong in here..

What am I doing wrong. I want to convert the canvas that have filter to url

`var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` gives me image without filter

Need help

Comment: `applyFilters` is async (that's why you pass a `renderAll` callback in it). You need to call toDataURL in its callback otherwise you're exporting the canvas before the filter is applied.

Comment: can you show the example

Comment: Since it will make your whole function async, you'll need to rewrite it but in broad lines : `function filter(url, callback) { ...(initCanvas)... var onend = function(){ canvas.renderAll(); var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); callback(img);}; ... Image.fromURL(..., function(oImg){ ... oImg.applyFilters(onend); canvas.add(oImg);}`

Comment: Its not working on mine.. can you please make answer with detail elaboration.. That would be so much helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applyFilters` is asynchronous (that's why you pass a `renderAll` callback in it).
You need to call toDataURL in its callback otherwise you're exporting the canvas before the filter is applied.

Here is a rough adaptation of your code :

```js
function filter(url, callback) {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.id = "canvas_greyscale";
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_greyscale');
  // the applyFilters' callback
  var onend = function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    callback(img);
  }

  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
    canvas.setDimensions({width:oImg.width, height:oImg.height});

    oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
    // here we pass the export function
    oImg.applyFilters(onend)
    
    canvas.add(oImg)
  }, {
    crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
  })
}

var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Supernumerary_rainbow_03_contrast.jpg'
filter(url, function(dataURI) {
  output.src = dataURI;
  original.src = url
})
```

```css
img{ width: 50%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.js"></script>
<img id="output"><br>
original Image: © Andrew Dunn CC-By-SA 2.0 <br>
<img id="original">
```

Comment: Also here I am doing `c.height = oImg.height` because `canvas.height = oImg.height` is giving me half of the image. What is the issue here.. I thing it should be canvas.height ?

Comment: @aryan, I just updated with what you should have done, just beore reading your comment ;-)